# Track react-native "IOS" or Android" application while uninstall

Tags: react-native

How track or find while **uninstall react-native application (IOS or Android).**

Answer (score 2):

You can check this package [AppsFlyer](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/react-native-appsflyer) which provides the unistall detector and you can also send an extra key of `platform:Platform.OS` to detect OS type .

**.Without Third Party Library**

This you can achieve through Push Notification. You can save device token with user email_id. So now you can send notification to all the registered devices and can filter out those devices along with their email_ids which were failed to receive notification.

Great answer by rajat, hope it helps.

Comment: If any possible "without using AppsFlyer". And i'm already implementing push notification via **react-native-firebase**. if there is any way to achieve this using **FCM**.